# Word for someone who promotes a product/idea that he/she is invested in

Tags: single-word-requests

The general idea is a conflict of interest. But, I am searching for an adjective or noun that describes this sort of behavior. All I can think of is self-serving or egoistic. Any thoughts?

Comment: "Implied". That is the word you are looking for. You can use the other forms "implicitly, implication, etc" depending on your sentence construction

Comment: "Implied" doesn't seem to have much to do with this, I don't think.

Comment: If it was a dodgy deal, the promoter might be 'implicated'; but if the promoter was taking advantage of privileged information, that would be 'insider dealing.'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**biased**
ˈbʌɪəst
adjective
unfairly prejudiced for or against someone or something.
"we will not tolerate this biased media coverage"

(Copied from Google's definition of the word)

Or a person promoting their **vested interests**

> a special interest in an existing system, arrangement, or institution
>   for particular personal reasons; the persons, groups, etc., who
>   benefit the most from existing business or financial systems

(dictionary.reference.com)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It crossed my mind, but "biased" gives the feeling of having the inclination rather than having the intent. As of now this is the closest answer. Maybe "self-serving bias" ?

Comment: @Eddy a little too passive? I think I see. How about "vested interests'? (I'll edit to include if you like)

Answer (score 5):

Another good word is **shill**. A shill is someone who promotes a product, for instance, leaving a review on Amazon, while secretly being affiliated with, or paid by, the sellers of the product.

From [dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/shill), second definition:

> a person who publicizes or praises something or someone for reasons of self-interest, personal profit, or friendship or loyalty.

Answer (score 2):

In the technology adoption arena, the term **evangelist** applies.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_evangelist

Answer (score 0):

My first thought when I read your question was to give the answer 'smart', but I know that's not what you mean. I think perhaps the answer you're seeking is 'mercenary'. For my mind, that's the best fit by far.

Comment: This is (the start of) a good answer. Please consider filling it out with an appropriate definition of _mercenary_ from a reputable dictionary, so interested readers will understand why it's a good option. If you add such a definition, please give proper credit to the dictionary you used, too. Thanks!